# How to put a for loop in this function file and have 2 vectors as output?

Tags: matlab

For an assignment I need to make a function file where I input 3 values and get 2 vectors as output.

To this end, I have created two separate function files `s1` and `s2` that have as input a vector and as output a value(in this context, it would have to be the amount of balls `N` that is in a vase, and the only information is the amount of `n` balls taken from the vase):

```
function s1=s1(x)
n=length(x);
s1=2*(sum(x)/n)-1;
end
```

---

```
function s2=s2(x)
n=length(x);
s2=((n+1)/n)*max(x)-1
end
```

Note that `s1` and `s2` contain separate formulas for determining `N`.

Now as I said, I am to create a new function file `test` where I insert 3 values `n`, `N`, `M` (`M` is the amount of times that random balls are taken from the vase), and have as output 2 vectors `y` and `z` that respectively contain all values of `s1` and `s2` (thus in both cases it needs to be a `Mx1` vector).

This is what I have for `test` now:

```
function [y,z] = test(N,n,M)
for k=1:M
y=s1(randperm(N,n));
z=s2(randperm(N,n));
end
```

Here the command `randperm(N,n)` selects a random amount of `n` balls every time from the total amount of N balls, so for example `randperm(10,3)` would give me 3 random numbers from the collection (1,2...10).

However, all this function seems to do is calculate the value `s2` a hundred times, and thus not even give me any vector at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is my function file not even cut out to do this at all?

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly what you are after, could please explain again. No functions, just the scenario and the math.

Comment: Is the assignment about matlab or about maths? If it's about matlab, didn't they teach you how to use it? You function's almost fine, you just have to define a vector when you want one: `y(k)=...; z(k)=...`. For maximum efficiency, pre-allocate before the for loop with `y=zeros(1,M); z=zeros(1,M);`, or equivalently, run the loop with `for k=M:-1:1`. The latter will start by assigning `y(M)` and `z(M) `first, thereby doing the allocation for you for the remaining `M-1` values of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values of `s1` and `s2` to `y` and `z` and overwriting the values that were previously in `y` and `z` during each iteration of the loop. At the end of the loop `y` and `z` only contain the last values computed by `s1` and `s2`.

You need to assign the returned values to different indices in the vectors `y` and `z` like

```
y(k) = s1(randperm(N, n));
z(k) = s2(randperm(N, n));
```

This assigns the value of `s1` to the k-th element of `y` (making it a vector) and the value of `s2` to the k-th element of `z`. Now, this will create a vector for `y` and `z` of length `M` because the `for` loop loops from `1` to `M`.

So the only change you need to make is to add `(k)` after `y` and `z` which will give

```
function [y, z] = test(N, n, M)
    for k = 1:M
        y(k) = s1(randperm(N, n));
        z(k) = s2(randperm(N, n));
    end
end
```

You may benefit from reading [Matrix Indexing in Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). It is a good article that explains the basics of how `(k)` works. There is a more advanced documentation too on [Matrix Indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

---

Aside: Just to note too. If you use the above code, Matlab will reallocate memory of `y` and `z` during each iteration of the loop as they become larger. It is usually more beneficial to preallocate space for `y` and `z` using a function like [`zeros`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html).

```
y = zeros(M, 1);
z = zeros(M, 1);
```

these create vectors for `y` and `z` of length `M` and fill them with `0`. They should be used in the function before the `for` loop like so

```
function [y, z] = test(N, n, M)
    y = zeros(M, 1);
    z = zeros(M, 1);
    for k = 1:M
        y(k) = s1(randperm(N, n));
        z(k) = s2(randperm(N, n));
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, as it seems definitely seems to be a step into the right direction since it now does give me a vector as a output, but this still happens after calculating s2 a hundred times(and not putting them in a vector) and then assigning the aforementioned vector to 'ans'. So y and z are pretty much still nowhere to be seen. Could it be there is something wrong with the function files s1 and s2 still?

Comment: @J.Sparrow have you considered learning matlab before trying to use it?

Comment: Well, I do sort of know the basics if that is what you want to know.

Comment: @J.Sparrow the reason the result is stored in `ans` is that you call the function without return arguments. If you instead call it as `[var1, var2]=test(N,n,M);` then `var1` will contain what is called `y` in the function, and `var2` will contain what is called `z`. This is one of the first things one should learn about defining functions, that's why I asked (and you ignored my earlier question whether this is a matlab course or a maths course).